# Changing logging level in log4net xml

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I've a c# 3.5 winforms desktop app running on production server.It uses log4net for logging.

The requirement is that the user should be able to switch the logging level at run time...for eg:if the level is switched to "INFO" level, then app shud write only info level logs.
Also, the business does not want to change the log level by going on to prod server and editing the log4net xml file.

Which one of the following approaches would be ok for this?Or is there any other better approach?
Have an "Admin" winform which will enable the user to change the log level.
The user will be logging on to app from their desktop.

1.And then In the app, I can load log4net xml from the network path using log4net api, save the changes with the new level provided from the UI and then re-instantiate the logger class with the new level.

or

2.Have 2 new tables in the backend....a look up table "A" with the level Ids and Names.And another table "B" with user name, current level id and date modified.

Update the level provided from UI screen in table B.
Using .net's Sqlcachedependency, whenever the value in the table B changes,re-instantiate the logger class with the new level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps if you go for the 1-st option it will be much easier.

You might want to copy log4net config file to the local user machine. Once user changed the level you save it locally to the xml. You can use this method to track changes in the log4net config

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch
```

Lastly, you will need to reinitialise the logger

Comment: thanks for your response.Sorry, if it is not clear from my question, but the code will be running on the server side.So,I'll have to make changes to the log xml file at the server side only.

Answer (score 1):

By default, log4net hooks a file change notification on it's config file and automatically reconfigures when the file is updated.  So, I'd think it would be the least work to have your UI hack the config file.  I would think the easiest approach all around would be to put a little web app on the server with the app ronning on the server with a simple UI for changing the log level in the log4net xml config file.

Comment: thanks for ur response...well, we are not supposed to have webapp[as per the business requirements]..so I believe, u r saying that I better use the first approach[of editing the xml using log4net api] instead of using Sqlcachedependency..right?

Comment: It is mostly true that log4net watches the file for changes.  It only watches it if you tell it to in the initialization and if you aren't using the app.config / web.config file but its own config file instead.  I would recommend taking this approach, coupled with your option one above (editing the file and replacing it).  This would make the most sense.  +1 for a good answer.